# Why am I getting output for -2//4 as -1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, integer, floor

I'm getting `-1` as output for `-2//4`.

```
print(-2//4)
```

Comment: _"Output should be 0 as per python."_ What do you mean "as per Python"? Why did you expect the result `0`? Can you walk us through that thought process?

Answer (score 2):

```
-2 divided by 4 == -0.5
```

In Python 3 the `//` operator produces the floor of the result

Floor will bring the number to the next lower integer

You are working with negative numbers, hence `-1` is less than `0`

```
 -2 / 4
>> -0.5

 math.floor(-0.5)
>> -1

 -2 // 4
>> -1
```

Comment: "In Python 3 the `//` operator calls a `math.floor()` on the result" - no it doesn't. It produces the floor of the exact result of the division, rather than calling `math.floor` on anything. This matters due to avoiding floating-point rounding.